Can a Java inner class have static initialization in bytecode?
This is NOT the same question as:
Why can't an inner class use static initializer?
or other similar ones, since it's unrelated to the Java language semantics and relates purely to bytecode and the class file format/JVM behaviour.
I'm doing some bytecode rewriting which involves adding synthetic static fields to classes. I was wondering if the JVM/bytecode spec allows me to add static fields and a <clinit> method to an inner class or not? So far nothing has complained, but I don't want to rely on something which I can't point to a bit of the spec for.
If not, it's frustrating since I'd have to walk up to the nearest non-inner class parent and add the fields there (except I'm transforming one class file at a time, so this becomes awkward).

You sure can. The restriction that inner classes cannot have static initialisers has already been lifted in modern Java versions.

"it's unrelated to the Java language semantics" - agreed, but why the [tag:java] tag then? (from its description: "Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself." ||| and this question is mostly better answered by testing (yourself - you know and probably have the context/framework/...)

Fair point. I guess I was just expecting that the Java tag would get the biggest audience of people who are experienced (most people who know JBC/JVM stuff are Java language people too, but it's not to other way round, so fair enough).

@Sweeper Thanks, that's good to know. I don't suppose you've got a link to a bit of the spec anywhere? I can try looking again too (esp. now it seems it should be stated explicitly somewhere).

@David Here is a link to the Java Specifications  It may not contain what you are looking for but it's a good link to have.

@David There is no "bit of the spec" that says this, because the restriction has been removed. You can compare section 8.1.3 of the newest spec with the same section in the Java 7 spec. That said, I don't think this was ever a restriction at the JVM level.

Yeah, I was suspecting I couldn't find it simply because (at the VM level) is was never a restriction. Thanks!

When inner classes were introduced in Java 1.1, no change to the bytecode format was made. In other words, inner classes are just classes like top level classes, except for a special attribute describing the relationship, which is used by compilers and by Reflection, but ignored by the JVM. Note that the linked section of the specification even says explicitly:

Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation does not check the consistency of an InnerClasses attribute against a class file representing a class or interface referenced by the attribute.

So, not only does the attribute have no effect on the actual execution, the JVM will not even check the plausibility of the contained information.
The ability of nested classes to access each others private members has been syntactic sugar until Java 11, implemented by the compiler by inserting synthetic helper methods. Java 11 introduced new attributes to allow true access without such helper methods, however, this feature is distinct from Java source code level inner classes.
So in short, since there are no special rules for inner classes on the bytecode level, a <clinit> method is allowed for inner classes.

Answer: Almost certainly yes.
From @Sweeper:

You sure can. The restriction that inner classes cannot have static
initialisers has already been lifted in modern Java versions.

Although at this time we can't find it explicitly mentioned in the spec, but likely because it was never a restriction at the VM level.
